# Is it possible to have nested proxy call in solidity?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

[image: example:]

I want have a design that allows me to change the implementation contract by only call upgradeTo() on 2nd layer proxy once. However, when I call real implementation function on 1st layer proxy, It prompt an error that the implementation is not exist.

How can do this kind of nested delegate call in solidity?

Answer (score 1):

use beacon proxy pattern
google openzepplin beacon proxy